# Macros taking code as an argument which can access parent arguments in LaTeX 3

Tags: macros, latex3, arguments

In Latex 3 I would like to be write a macro which takes as an argument code which can internally define a macro. How do I do this in a way that allows the code being passed to access arguments of the original. For example I would like to be able to do something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, expl3}

\begin{document}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\CodeMacro}{m +m}
{
    Do Something

    #2
}


\CodeMacro{Test}
{
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\csname Testing#1\endcsname{m}
    {
        #1-##1
    }
}

\end{document}
```

I would like this to expand to

```
Do Something

\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname TestingTest\endcsname{m}
{
    Test-#1
}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname Testing#1\endcsname{}`, but you should think about whether this is needed at all. By the way, `xparse` loads `expl3` already and on document level, you don't use `LaTeX 3` code at all at the moment

Comment: Just curiosity or do you have some application in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\DeclareDocumentCommand` to begin with; the command has its uses, but in general you should prefer `\NewDocumentCommand`.

What you seem to need is a function like `\NewNamedDocumentCommand`, plus some dirty trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn % or spaces would count
\NewDocumentCommand{\CodeMacro}{m +m}
 {
   Do Something
   \nate_do:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewNamedDocumentCommand}{mmm}
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nate_do:nn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__nate_do:n { #2 }
  \__nate_do:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CodeMacro{Test}{%
  \NewNamedDocumentCommand{Testing#1}{m}{%
        #1-##1%
  }%
}

\TestingTest{X}

\end{document}
```

[image]