# How to create a document command that has a name that is not known in advance?

Tags: latex3, xparse

I'd like to create a LaTeX3 function, `\my_func`, that has a single parameter, `#1`, which is expected to be initialized to a LaTeX3 string. `\my_func` is to create a new document command using `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand`, whose name is the one passed as argument to `\my_func`. How can I do so?

To give a concrete usage example, there's a bunch of mathematical functions that I wish to define. I'm still not sure what symbols I wish to use to represent them, though. So I define macros `\func1`, `\func2`, etc. with rather long and expressive names, e.g. `\LeftProjectionOfTheSecondDegree`. These names won't change, but the symbols that represent them on paper may change later on.

Each of these functions can appear either standalone, or inside a bigger expression. When used inside a bigger expression, the functions always take arguments. However when they are used on their own, I need to express how many arguments they take, so I use subscripts, but these subscripts should not appear when the functions are part of a larger expression, because then the number of arguments can be easily deduced from the context.

Comment: Could you please add an example of supposed usage?

Comment: However, `\exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand {#1}{...}{...}` should do as code in `\my_func:n`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378345/4427

Comment: @egreg: I've added a supposed usage example. It doesn't compile, but hopefully it conveys the gist of what I'm after.

Comment: @EvanAad egreg already answered your question in his comment. Is that what you are after? By the way, this is a weird option, you plan to use `\use:c {foo}` inside the `\foo` command? That gives you an infinite loop. And, apart from that, are you looking precisely for a way of having a macro that works out and in of math mode? You have `\ensuremath` for that.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, it is what I'm after. His 2nd comment answers my question.

Comment: @Manuel: `\ensuremath` is not suitable for my purposes. I'd like to create a shortcut for a rather long math expression that I can use either standalone or inside a bigger formula. When I use it standalone, I'd like to avoid typing the enclosing dollar signs.

Comment: @EvanAad egreg answers *`\my_func` is to create a new document command using xparse's `\NewDocumentCommand`, whose name is the one passed as argument to `\my_func`*. But your current *definition* wouldn't compile either. By the way, you are not following the expl3 naming conventions, and using `xparse` to define a command that should be defined with `\cs_new_protected:Nn`.

Comment: @EvanAad `\ensuremath` is precisely for that. Then aren't you looking for `\NewDocumentCommand \savelongexpression { m m } { \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { } { \ensuremath{#2} }`? This way you can say `\savelongexpression{foo}{\log^{\exp ression}}` and use `\foo` wherever you want.

Comment: Still it is unclear why you need the name as opposed to the control sequence. Can you give a better example?

Comment: @egreg: Simply to avoid typing 1 character, namely the backslash. But since I use this meta-function repeatedly, this is a bigg-ish saving of typing.

Comment: By typing two? `\foo` vs `{foo}`.

Comment: @Manuel: No, `{foo}` instead of `{\foo}`. After all, mandatory arguments of functions created with xparse must be inside curly braces, no?

Comment: @EvanAad I don't think this is a big gain anyway; the example?

Comment: @egreg: I'd add an example, but you (in your 2nd comment above) as well as Manuel in his answer below, have already answered my question satisfactorily, so it seems redundant at this point. But if you think I should still add an example, I will.

Comment: @EvanAad I'm particularly interested in the variants you have in mind, which is a rather cryptic part in the question.

Comment: @egreg: I'll give you an idea of the variants involved. There's a bunch of mathematical functions that I wish to define. I'm still not sure what symbols I wish to use to represent them, though. So I define macros `\func1`, `\func2`, etc. with rather long and expressive names. These names won't change, but the symbols that represent them on paper may change later on.

Comment: @egreg: Each of these functions can appear either standalone, or inside a bigger expression. When used inside a bigger expression, the functions always take arguments. However when they are used on their own, I need to express how many arguments they take, so I use subscripts, but these subscripts should not appear when the functions are part of a larger expression, because then the number of arguments can be easily deduced from the context.

Comment: Is it so difficult to edit the question for adding the details?

Comment: @egreg: I've edited my question to add these details. Is it OK now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are precisely looking for `\ensuremath`, I think. `\ensuremath` ensures that its contents is typeset inside math mode: are you in math mode? ok, just put the code; are you out of math mode? ok, then type `$..$` around the expression.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentcommand\savelongexpression{mm}{\NewDocumentCommand#1{}{\ensuremath{#2}}

\savelongexpression\nameone{x^2 + y^2}
\savelongexpression\nametwo{\sin x \cos x}

\begin{document}

\nameone{} and \nametwo. Also $\nameone + \nametwo$, and
\[
  \nameone - \nametwo
\]
too.

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to add `{}` or any alternative after the command if you want the space tokenized.

Comment: There's no need to use `xparse` here in this part since we don't use any of its features. But nothing wrong with using it, either.

Comment: Well, there's some piece of the puzzle I didn't mention: when the expression is used standalone, it looks slightly differently than when it is used inside a bigger expression. Specifically, when used standalone, the superscript ^{S,T} should be appended to it; this superscript can be deduced from the context when the expression is used inside a bigger expression, so it can be left off under those circumstances. This is why I wanted to use an optional star.

Comment: Then we can't make use of `\ensuremath`, we need to substitute `\ensuremath{#2}` by `\mode_if_math:TF { #2 } { $ \relax #2^{S,T} $ }`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! By the way, why is the `\relax` needed?

Comment: It's present in `\ensuremath` and it has to do probably with the fact that `$` expands things to look for another `$`, but I really don't remember right now the exact reason. Or may be because if it wasn't present, `\ensuremath{}` would output `$$` which would open display math, rather than giving an empty math `$\relax$`.

Comment: So in my case, the `\relax` might be left out safely, right?

Comment: Probably yes...